# Trim Wordpress Post Title

Tags: php, wordpress

Following PHP code shows WordPress media files at user front end

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'author' => $current_user->ID,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
);
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<tr><td><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'" rel="shadowbox" title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'">';
echo $attachment->_wp_attached_file;
echo '</a>      
</td>
}
}?>
```

Above code shows the complete file name at front end. If someone upload sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.txt, 123457xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.gif **or xls, pdf, docx and all other extensions with different long file names** it create mess on my theme. Can anyone please help guide me how to trim the file name and show something like sssssss...ssss.txt xxxxxx...xxxx.pdf or gif at front end?

I tried following function for specific file in functions.php still no change

```
$wp_attached_file = 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.txt';
echo preg_replace('/(.{3}).*(\..{2,4})/', '$1...$2', $wp_attached_file);
```

and

```
$attachment = $wp_attached_file;
echo preg_replace('/(.{3}).*(\..{2,4})/', '$1...$2', $wp_attached_file);
```

It is working now, I replace following line

```
echo ($attachment->_wp_attached_file);
```

with

```
echo preg_replace('/(.{15}).*(.{5})(\..{2,4})/', '$1...$2$3', $attachment->_wp_attached_file);
```

Comment: Setup validation so users can't upload something like that?

Comment: You could trim the output with a regex, https://regex101.com/r/aR1vJ2/2.

Comment: I don't think regex is the appropriate solution for validating or sanitizing user input.

Comment: @ChrisBurton OP said nothing about validating/sanitizing only `it create mess on my theme`. It is true it does nothing to validate/sanitize but it wasn't suppose to.

Comment: "If **someone**" is the keyword. When it comes to user input, you should ALWAYS validate and sanitize.

Comment: The file has already been uploaded at this point.

Comment: My point exactly. You should always validate and sanitize user input. The OP's issue could be prevented if this was in place. Rather than after the fact.

Comment: @chris85 thanks for your reply, can you please guide me how can I add $regex in the code `$attachments = get_posts( $args );
$regex =  '#(.{3}).*(\..{2,4})#';
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
 echo '<tr><td><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'" rel="shadowbox" title="'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'">';
 echo ($attachment->_wp_attached_file);
 echo '</a>  
 </td>';`

Comment: @jugnu as noted in previous comments the regex solution doesn't validate/sanitize the input provided by the user. I presume the WP framework takes care of that and you just want to trim down long names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like

```
/(.{3}).*(\..{2,4})/
```

This captures the first three characters, `(.{3})`.
Then ignores everything, `.*`
Until the last period and the next 2-4 characters (for `ai`, `mpeg`, `jpg` could filter that to `3` if it will always be 3), `\..{2,4}`. The `.{2,4}` bit being any character 2-4 strings long.

PHP Usage:

```
$wp_attached_file = 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss.txt';
echo preg_replace('/(.{3}).*(\..{2,4})/', '$1...$2', $wp_attached_file);
```

Output:

```
sss....txt
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aR1vJ2/2